# Split text file Path to (x) number of files with VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, file, split, directory

I searched everywhere on stackoverflow.com but still not have a solution:

My code is very simple :

```
'Get Full Path of File
Dim elements As String = Path.GetTempPath() & "file.txt"
'Create A new folder for outputs if not exist
If (Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(Path.GetTempPath() & "folder")) Then
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetTempPath() & "folder")
End If
```

I want divide the file.txt with contents to (x) number of files inside the new folder

example :

if x = 3

the output files will be created automatically:

/folder/file_1.txt

/folder/file_2.txt

/folder/file_3.txt

Comment: Do you want to create a `x` number of identical files named using a variable as the source of the progression? Empty files? Do you also need to split the **content** of the original file?

Comment: No, the original file is not empty, i want to divite contents in file to multiple files

Comment: What are the criteria used to split the content of the original file? The number of lines, maybe (since it's a text file)? Something else?

Comment: The main thing is to have the content divided into multiple text files

Comment: Based on what logic?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198885/discussion-between-anass-el-fakir-and-jimi).

Comment: There's nothing to chat about. If you have a piece of paper and you need to divide it in a number of smaller pieces, how do you decide where to cut? What is the logic that lets you determine the size of the smaller pieces? You have to provide this logic.

Comment: I don't know what is the best way, this is why i'm asked this question have you any idea ?

Comment: What I asked is not about the *best way*. I about the logic used to divide *something* into smaller pieces. Another important matter is the use of these smaller files. Do you need to show the content somewhere? Why do you need to split that file? What are you going to do with the new files?

Comment: I explained everything dear Jimi, why you want to know what I do with these files? I want to split large files into multiple files that's all with vb.net using any logic

Comment: The logic and methods used to split a text file are not the same used to split a binary file. It also depends on the use of the text files. If you want to show their content somewhere, for example. You can assume there's a reason why I asked those questions. You can also assume that these details are important to receive a meaningful answer.

Comment: No i don't want to show their content somewhere, i just want to save them in the created folder, nothing else.

Comment: May be you should get file size, Devide with x, and write your destination files, and each has size of size/x.

Comment: "I want to split large files into multiple files that's all " So, if you had a 500MB file it would be OK to divide it into 3 files, the first with 1K, the second witn 1K and the third with the rest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Read the data from the existing text file.
2. Divide the data into an arbitrary number of strings of arbitrary length.
3. If the new directory doesn't exist create it.
4. Create files in this directory to store the arbitrary sections of data until an arbitrary number of files have been created and all data has been stored.

Since you refuse to provide the logic (I guess it is a secret), I will have to make some assumptions.

1. The original file contains lines that are approximately the same length.
2. The intent is divide the original file into files of approximately equal size.
3. The number of files is based on the size of the original file.

I split the files based on lines so a word would not be split between 2 files.

```vb
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim OriginalFilePath = "C:/devlist.txt" '16KB file
    Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines(OriginalFilePath)
    Dim NumOfLines = lines.Length
    Dim NumOfFiles As Integer = GetNumberOfFiles(OriginalFilePath, NumOfLines)
    If NumOfFiles = -1 Then
        MessageBox.Show("No data in file.")
        Return
    End If
    'The "\" operator is integer division
    Dim LinesPerFile = NumOfLines \ NumOfFiles
    'Dim LeftoverLines = NumOfLines Mod NumOfFiles - didn't need this afterall
    Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\Some Directory")
    Dim StartIndex As Integer
    Dim EndIndex As Integer
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder
    For i = 0 To NumOfFiles - 1
        EndIndex = StartIndex + LinesPerFile
        If EndIndex >= NumOfLines - 1 Then
            EndIndex = NumOfLines - 1
        End If
        For index = StartIndex To EndIndex
            sb.AppendLine(lines(index))
        Next
        Dim NewFilePath = $"C:\Some Directory\SplitFile{i.ToString}.txt"
        '.WriteAllText will create the new file or overwrite it if it exists
        File.WriteAllText(NewFilePath, sb.ToString)
        StartIndex = EndIndex + 1
        sb.Clear()
    Next
End Sub

Private Function GetNumberOfFiles(FilePath As String, NumOfLines As Integer) As Integer
    Dim OriginalFileLength = New FileInfo(FilePath).Length
    Dim NumOfFiles As Integer
    Select Case OriginalFileLength
        Case 0
            MessageBox.Show("No data in file")
            Return -1
        Case 1
            NumOfFiles = 1
        Case 2
            If NumOfLines < 2 Then
                NumOfFiles = 1
            End If
            NumOfFiles = 2
        Case 3 To 10_000
            If NumOfLines < 3 Then
                NumOfFiles = NumOfLines
            Else
                NumOfFiles = 3
            End If
            'You can continue the If statements but I assumed
            'a file of this size would have at least 4 lines
        Case 10_001 To 100_000
            NumOfFiles = 4
        Case 100_001 To 500_000
            NumOfFiles = 5
        Case Else
            NumOfFiles = 6
    End Select
    Return NumOfFiles
End Function
```

Result of splitting the 16KB file

[image]

Comment: May be the remain can be inserted to the last new file

Comment: @user11982798 All the data is included in one of the four files. The last file might be smaller than the rest.

Comment: Thank you Mary, but i there are some errors in this lines : Case 3 To 10_000 and  Case 10_001 To 100_000 and Case 100_001 To 500_000

Comment: @AnassElFakir Sorry for the errors. This may depend on the version of Visual Studio you are using. I am using 2019 and this version allows the underscore "_" character as a separator in numbers to make the code easier to read. Try just removing the underscore. (10_001 to 10001) on any of the numbers that have the underscore.

Answer (score 0):

This just sample

```
    Dim Divider = 3
    Dim myNewFile(Divider - 1) As String
    Dim fileReader As String
    fileReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("C:\test.txt")
    Dim myNewSize As Long = 0
    Long.TryParse(fileReader.Length / Divider, myNewSize)
    If myNewSize = 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Can't Be Processed")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    For myCnt As Int16 = 0 To divider - 1
        myNewFile(myCnt) = fileReader.Substring(myCnt * myNewSize + 1, myNewSize)
    Next

    'Resize The Last For Include The Remain
    Dim myNewLastSize As Long = myNewSize + fileReader.Length - myNewSize * Divider
    myNewFile(Divider - 1) = fileReader.Substring((Divider - 1) * myNewSize + 1, myNewLastSize)
```

And then you should save each split data to each it's table

Comment: Why do you expect the division to return a Long? Please turn on Option Strict. This is a 2 part process. First for the current project - In Solution Explorer double click My Project. Choose Compile on the left. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. Second for future projects - Go to the Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. This will save you from bugs at runtime.

Comment: Please don't use Mid in new code. Try the .net version which is .SubString

Comment: .TryParse takes a string as the first argument. `fileReader.Length / Divider` is not a string.

Comment: Why don't you actually try your answer in Visual Studio before posting.

Comment: ok thanks for the comment, I can get any knowledge for it, the next I will try to net minded...but still need reminding for the mistake